# Implications of the Buckingham-Pi theorem

Tags: dimensional-analysis

According to the pi-theorem any dimensionally homogenous equation
$$f(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) = x_N$$
can be expressed as another function of dimensionless variable products
$$g(\pi_1, \pi_2, \ldots) = 0.$$
Now, quite a few sources (see references here https://github.com/cheind/sympy-nondim) state the following without proof: Consider a particular solution $G$ in which the number of dimensionless products is 1
$$G(\pi_1) = 0,$$
then it follows that
$$ \pi_1 = C, $$ for unknown constant C. That is, in case the number of dimensionless products is 1, it follows that $\pi_1$ must be constant itself.

I thought about this statement for a while and have come to the conclusion that it can only be true if we make additional assumptions about $G$: Notice,

1. Since $G$ is a function is dimensionless and so is its independent variable,  it may take any functional form.
2. From $G(\pi_1) = 0$ follows that $\pi_1$ must be a root of $G$.
   Hence, $\pi_1 = C$ can only be true when $G$ has a single root (or maybe a small finite number of them)?

Is my reasoning correct and if so, does $G$ in actual physical problems behave that way?

Comment: what is the distinguished between G and g?

Comment: @Eli g refers to the general statement of the buckingham-pi, whereas G represents a particular solution for a specific problem in which it turns out that the number of dimless products is 1.

Comment: Clearly $G(\pi_1)$ is a one dimensional function (assuming $\pi_1$ can vary). But this function may have multiple zero. So, although $G(\pi_1)=0$ fixes $\pi_1$ to be be a constant, there may be multiple constants corresponding to multiple zero. As a physical example consider for instance the radar cross-section of a sphere.

Comment: Thanks. So, $G(\pi_1)=0 \implies \pi_1 = C$ is inaccurate in that we at need at least consider a finite number of potentially multiple roots: something along the lines of $G(\pi_1)=0 \implies \pi_1 \in \{C_1,C_2,\ldots,C_N\}$. Using the pi-theorem to guide the experiments might therefore yield $C_1$ for some experiments and $C_j$ for others. I can't follow on the radar cross-section examples, since it seems to have dim. $L^2$ and is not dimensionless?